# How can we create campaigns in SAP Hybris by uploading a CSV file?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In SAP Hybris On Premise, is it possible to create campaigns using a CSV file? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible with impex import but if csv include any mistake, you will get huge problems about price. I think you need get detail about story. You know hybris update promotions version by version with extra protection (synchronization, workflow for approve).

Comment: There is not much details for Impox import for 'Campaigns'. Please let me know if you could provide more details/pdfs anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Commerce doesn't have out-of-the-box types for campaigns, so the short answer is no. There's another SAP product called "SAP Marketing" to manage campaigns. SAP Commerce and SAP Marketing have some pre-built integrations, such as sending customers and products from commerce to marketing so campaigns can be created.